# Thunderbolt 2 to HDMI to VGA not detected, Thunderbolt 2&3 to HDMI to DVI-D (dual-link) black display

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hdmi, dvi, vga

I had a temporary windows laptop that used an HDMI connector so I bought converters that one way or another got to HDMI, and I plan on getting two HDMI connected monitors when the right time comes (more RAM vs new monitor decision).
I currently have a 2015 Macbook Air 11" and a  2020 Macbook Pro 13". Both detect a monitor and let me move the mouse to the secondary display but show a black screen when connecting via Thunderbolt 2/3 to an HDMI cable and then to DVI-D (dual-link). The Air also doesn't detect any monitor when connecting it through thunderbolt 2 to HDMI then to a VGA cable, which the Pro is fine with. Any ideas on either situation?